# Random numbers in a column based on another column's value

Tags: r, random, data.table

Good day all,

I'm struggling with creating a column which would populate the values using a random value generating value function which takes another column's value as an argument.

A bit of a context - I have a data table with lead time in a column:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(Item = rep(123456,each = 1000), LT = rnorm(1000,mean = 10, sd = 3))
```

and a function:

```
rand_ddlt_norm <- function(Lt,mean,sd){
  sign(Lt) * ( sum( rnorm( floor(abs(Lt)), mean, sd) ) +
                 rnorm(1, mean, sd) * ( abs(Lt)%%1) )
}
```

The above function is designed to calculate demand during the lead time for each row.

Unfortunately, I cannot do that:

```
dt[,ddlt := rand_ddlt_norm(LT, mean = 100, sd = 30)]
```

because all rows will be populated with the same number.

I could obviously put it into a loop, but for 10,000 iterations, 20,000+ products and numerous distribution types, the computation time is getting ridiculous.

I would graciously welcome any suggestions about how this code could be optimised without running a loop.

Comment: The function you create requests variables `LT`, `est11` and `est12`. However, when you try to create your data table, you supply `LT`,`mean` and `sd`. Do you mean to use `LT`, `est11` and `est12` there, too?

Comment: good capture, thank you, my brain isn't working anymore. that'll teach me retyping the code rather than pasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Vectorize()` to vectorize your function.

```
# data
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

dt <- data.table::data.table(Item = rep(123456,each = 1000), LT = rnorm(1000,mean = 10, sd = 3))

# def function
rand_ddlt_norm <- function(Lt,est11,est12){
  sign(Lt) * ( sum( rnorm( floor(abs(Lt)), est11, est12) ) +
                 rnorm(1, est11, est12) * ( abs(Lt)%%1) )
}

rand_ddlt_norm <- Vectorize(rand_ddlt_norm) # vectorize it

dt[,ddlt := rand_ddlt_norm(LT, 100,30)]
```

Result:

```
> head(dt)
     Item        LT      ddlt
1: 123456  8.120639  845.6967
2: 123456 10.550930 1112.5837
3: 123456  7.493114  733.3808
4: 123456 14.785842 1516.8916
5: 123456 10.988523 1101.0449
6: 123456  7.538595  898.3760
```

Comment: Suggest `set.seed(1)` to make the example the same in perpetuity.

Comment: this is amazing, I've never used Vectorize() before. It' going to be my best friend I feel now!

Comment: problem is that the solution is slower than directly vectorizing the function, which can make a big difference when the data is big

Comment: @denis That's true. You can also use `purrr::map()` like `dt[,ddlt := purrr::map(.x = LT, .f = function(x) rand_ddlt_norm(x, mean = 100, sd = 30))]`. This is faster than both solutions provided.

Comment: Copy the `set.seed(1)` before the creation of `dt` since it is also randomly generated.

Comment: @JdeMello Wow didn't know the `purrr::map` function, thanks for the trick

Answer (score 3):

I would propse you vectorize your function directly :

```
rand_ddlt_norm_vec <- function(Lt,mean,sd){
  sign(Lt) * ( rowSums( t(sapply(1:length(Lt),function(x){rnorm(floor(abs(Lt)),mean,sd)})))  +
                 rnorm(length(Lt), mean, sd) * ( abs(Lt)%%1) )
}
```

Where Lt is now a vector. Here

```
t(sapply(1:length(Lt),function(x){rnorm(floor(abs(Lt)),mean,sd)}))
```

create a matrice that has the same number of row than Lt, and the same number of column than `floor(abs(Lt))`. You then use `Rowsum` to get a vector.

To compare with the solution of JdeMello:

```
rand_ddlt_norm_vec2 <- Vectorize(rand_ddlt_norm)

library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(Item = rep(123456,each = 10000), LT = rnorm(10000,mean = 10, sd = 3))

    microbenchmark(
      denis = function(){dt[,ddlt := rand_ddlt_norm_vec(LT, mean = 100, sd = 30)]},
      jdeMello = function(){dt[,ddlt := rand_ddlt_norm_vec2(LT, mean = 100, sd = 30)]}
    )

Unit: nanoseconds
     expr min lq  mean median uq  max neval cld
    denis   0  0  0.24      0  0    1   100   a
 jdeMello   0  0 25.88      0  0 2566   100   a
```

This solution is 100 time faster than JdeMello solution.